# Can you change the display name (and other properties) of an existing Windows serivce programatically?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I want users to be able to change the display name of an existing Windows service using our configuration tool. In code, given an instance of the corresponding ServiceController object, setting its DisplayName property seems to have effect. Tried calling Refresh, which seemed to have no effect. The MSDN doc is a little unclear on what Refresh does - does it reread the current service settings or does it write my changes to the service? Code is simple:

```
ServiceController sc = GetServiceController(CurrentInterfaceData.ServiceName);
sc.DisplayName = "MyService";
sc.Refresh();
```

Comment: "Tried calling Refresh, which seemed to have no effect" .. on *what*?

Comment: On either the display name as displayed in the Services control panel or the contents of the variables while debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Use WMI. For that you have to add a reference to System.Management assembly. Here is excerpt of a working code that I had used for a generic installer:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UpdateService("ipsecd");
    }

    private const int LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS = 9;
    private const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50 = 3;
    private const int SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS = 0xF01FF;
    private const int SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS = 0xF003F;
    private const uint SERVICE_NO_CHANGE = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    private const uint SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS = 0x00000010;
    private const uint SERVICE_INTERACTIVE_PROCESS = 0x00000100;
    // Win32 function to connect to remote machine
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern Boolean LogonUser(string lpUsername, string lpDomain, string lpPassword, int dwLogonType,
                                            int dwLogonProvider, out IntPtr phToken);

    // Win32 function to connect to impersonate user
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(IntPtr hToken);

    // Win32 function to open the service control manager
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr OpenSCManager(string lpMachineName, string lpDatabaseName, int dwDesiredAccess);

    // Win32 function to open a service instance
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr OpenService(IntPtr hSCManager, string lpServiceName, int dwDesiredAccess);

    // Win32 function to change the service config
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern Boolean ChangeServiceConfig(
        IntPtr hService,
        UInt32 nServiceType,
        UInt32 nStartType,
        UInt32 nErrorControl,
        String lpBinaryPathName,
        String lpLoadOrderGroup,
        IntPtr lpdwTagId,
        [In] char[] lpDependencies,
        String lpServiceStartName,
        String lpPassword,
        String lpDisplayName);


    public static void UpdateService(string serviceName)
    {
        ManagementScope scope = null;            
        ObjectQuery filter = new ObjectQuery(string.Format("SELECT * FROM Win32_Service WHERE Name = '{0}'", serviceName));
        ManagementObjectSearcher query = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, filter);
        try
        {
            ManagementObjectCollection services = query.Get();
            // No match = failed condition
            if (services.Count == 0)                
                return;
            foreach (ManagementObject service in services)
            {
                SetServiceDisplayName(serviceName, "new disp name");
                service.Dispose();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Could not set property
        }

    }

    private static void SetServiceDisplayName(string name, string dispName)
    {            
        IntPtr svcHndl = OpenService("", "", name);
        // Call the ChangeServiceFailureActions() abstraction of ChangeServiceConfig2()
        bool rslt = ChangeServiceConfig(svcHndl, SERVICE_NO_CHANGE,
            SERVICE_NO_CHANGE, SERVICE_NO_CHANGE, null, null, IntPtr.Zero, null, null, null, dispName);            
    }

    private static IntPtr OpenService(string userName, string password, string serviceName)
    {
        IntPtr scmHndl = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr svcHndl = IntPtr.Zero;
        // Open the service control manager
        scmHndl = OpenSCManager("", null, SC_MANAGER_ALL_ACCESS);

        if (scmHndl.ToInt32() <= 0)
            return IntPtr.Zero;

        // Open the service
        svcHndl = OpenService(scmHndl, serviceName, SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS);

        if (svcHndl.ToInt32() <= 0)
            return IntPtr.Zero;

        return svcHndl;
    }
}
```

Try it. It should work.

Comment: Excellent. Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the name of the Windows Service is set when the service is installed.  I don't think that changing it later will have any effect.